# Are there any Taizé worship services in Bergen?

Tags: norway, religion, bergen

I'm now in Bergen for a few days, and I was wondering if there is a Taizé workship similar to the one I usually go where I live (Rome, see its [Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/groups/135858886512776/))

Are there any Taizé services in Bergen? If so, how could I make contact and join the prayer service?

Comment: I suggest contacting them (in English) to ask: http://www.bergenchurch.no/

Answer (score 1):

After lengthy and numerous Google searches for Taizé events, meetings, followers, practitioners, formal or informal, the conclusion is that none are  currently being held in Norway.

In 2010, a weekend meeting was held in Oslo and Trondheim, the invitation of the Norges Kristne Råd, the Christian Council of Norway. You might [contact the Council](http://www.norgeskristnerad.no/index.cfm?id=354740) to ask about thost that worship with a similar style of ecuminism.

Otherwise, it might be best to contact [Taizé community](https://www.taize.fr/en_article332.html)  directly.